# Centering Every Element in a table on LaTex

Tags: pdf, latex, pdflatex, biblatex

How to centering all elements in a table on laTex.
I have tried \begin{center} method but it didn't work for me.
Any other idea?
Please help.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understood you're question correct or not, but here's an example of how to center the content inside a cell:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
            \hline
            Centered Text& Also Centered \\
            \hline
            Text& Also Centered \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        \caption{Caption}
        \label{tab:my_label}
    \end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

When you're using `\begin{center}` and `end{center}` the whole environment will be centered.
The `c` in the tabular environment specify that the content inside a cell should be centered.